# opencart product options within options

Tags: opencart, e-commerce

I am interested in creating different product options within options in Opencart.  For example, I am selling art prints in various sizes and would like to add an additional option of framing, however the price of the frame must change according to the print size.  So if a customer chooses a print of 11 in x 18 in, the framing price would display as less than if they opted for an 18 in x 24in.  How can I do this in Opencart so the framing price will automatically adjust depending on print size?

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to just say "Google it" but what you are looking for is an extension that implements "Dependent Options" of which there are several.

There are many in the extension store but a Google Search works better than the built-in search, so try these:
https://www.google.com/search?q=opencart+dependent+options

As always look for extensions from reputable OpenCart developers with loads of downloads, 5 star votes and positive comments.

Here is an example:
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=13882

838 sales. 5 stars and "MarketInSG" are well known and good developers.

Answer (score 0):

Go to products->edit(or) add product->option tab. Here you can add the sizes of the product. once you add one size you automatically get the price tab. You can decrease or increase the price of your product for that specific size there.